# PHP Threaded Closure Error GuzzleHttp/client

Tags: php, multithreading, class, closures, guzzle

I use **zts-php** for threaded works i have closure error guzzle client is not serialization `$this->client`  , i use `$client` is working how i add `run()` function `guzzlehttp client`?

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise;
use GuzzleHttp\TransferStats;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\PromiseInterface;
class check extends Thread 

{
 function __construct(string $url,int $timeout=60)
    {
        $this->client= new Client([

                'timeout' => $timeout
            ]);
          $this->timeout = $this->timeout;     
    }

    public function run() {

        $response =    $this->client->request('head', "http://www.google.com", [
                'on_stats' => function (TransferStats $stats) {
                    $this->uri = $stats->getEffectiveUri();
                    $this->transferTime = $stats->getTransferTime();
                }
    ]);

  }

}
```

I get **Error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in
```